# CSS/HTML How to put two blocks next to each other

Tags: html, css

I wanna know how I could put these two blocks next to eachother, "News" and "Popular Projects", http://jsfiddle.net/2cQr9/ I tried several times but it didn't work out.

**HTML**

```
<div class="topMsg">
    <h2> News</h2>
    <a>lorem</a>
</div>
<div class="popMsg">
    <h2>Popular Projects</h2>
    <h3>Skin Selector</h3>
    <a> Elorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum</a>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    background-color:#000;  
}

a{
    text-decoration:none;
}



.topMsg{

    width:400px;
    margin:100px 50px;
    text-align:justify
}

.topMsg a,.popMsg a{
    color:#FFF; 
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.topMsg h2, .popMsg h2{
    color:#069;
    font-size:32px;
}

.popMsg{
    width:250px;
    margin:100px 50px;
    text-align:justify;
}

.popMsg h3{
    color:#028;
}
```

Comment: What is that dot supposed to mean?

Comment: `.topMsg, .popMsg { float: left; }`

Comment: floating, `display: table-cell`, `display: inline-block`, flexbox: there are many ways of positioning them and it has been answered A LOT if you search a liitle

Answer (score 0):

If there is enough space for both of them next to eachother (margin/padding counts as space as well!) you can simply `float:left;` them.

Answer (score 0):

You can had display:inline-block; to .topMsg and popMsg

```
 .topMsg{

    width:400px;
    margin:100px 50px;
    text-align:justify;
        display:inline-block;
   }

 .popMsg{

    width:250px;
    margin:100px 50px;
    text-align:justify;
        display:inline-block;
   }
```

[check the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2cQr9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS code to the elements:

```
.popMsg{ float:left; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, DIV element is in `display:block`.

You just need to change the display of your ".popMsg" and ".topMsg" div.

```
.popMsg, .topMsg{
   display:inline; 
   float:left;
}
```

or

```
.popMsg, .topMsg{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: First CSS code: as soon as an element floats, the computed value of display WILL be block per definition, whatever the value you try to set. Just try with different values to see it has no effect. CSS2.1 REC [Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo) (except table and inline-table, run-in and obviously `none`)

Comment: I'm used to set display:inline for float elements. It corrects a "Double margin bug" which occurs in IE6 (I still got clients on IE6..)

Comment: Then use a conditional comment, class or at least a hack. And how will the second CSS code work in IE6?

Comment: You're right. The second CSS code won't work for IE6 (and IE7 I guess).

Answer (score 0):

put following lines at the end of your CSS:

```
    div.topMsg { float:left; }
    div.popMsg { float:right; }
    div.footer { clear:both; }
```

now its left & right as you wanted